# Why do I use double quotes in shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I understand the usage single quote and double quote.

but I don't know situation need to double quotes in the script.

there is no diff that statements

```
$ echo hello world! $1
$ echo "hello world! $1"
```

please show me diff between normal and double quotes.

Comment: Word splitting in bash is controlled by the `IFS` variable ("*internal field separator*") which defaults to `IFS=$' \t\n'` (`space`, `tab`, `newline`). If you do not quote your variables *word splitting* occurs on any character in `IFS` (you can set `IFS` to control this). Quoting will effect *file/path name expansion* as well.

Answer (score 5):

Let's consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls foo*
foo111.txt  foo11.txt  foo1.txt
```

Let's consider a minor variation on your script:

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/sh
echo No quotes $1
echo "Double quotes $1"
```

Now, let's run it:

```
$ bash script "foo*"
No quotes foo111.txt foo11.txt foo1.txt
Double quotes foo*
```

As you can see, the results are completely different.  Without the double quotes, *pathname expansion* is performed.

To illustrate another difference:

```
$ bash script "long              space"
No quotes long space
Double quotes long              space
```

With double quotes, the long space between words is preserved.  Without it, all contiguous whitespace is replaced with a single blank.  This is an example of *word splitting*.

Answer (score 1):

An example might demonstrate the use

1. To accommodate string with spaces

   ```
   var=file name # Not the intended effect.
   ```

   `file` is stored in a `var` and `name` is taken by shell as a separate cmd which gives you an error.
2. To prevent word splitting

   ```
   var="file name"
   cp $var newfile
   ```

   Here $var expands to `file name` and in effect, the command would become

   ```
   cp file name newfile
   ```

   and cp would take `file` and `name` as 2 source files and `newfile` as  the destination *directory* which gives you the error:

   ```
   cp: target 'newfile' is not a directory
   ```

   If there really exists a directory named 'newfile', it will give error:

   ```
   cp: cannot stat 'file': No such file or directory
   cp: cannot stat 'name': No such file or directory
   ```

   The correct method is

   ```
   cp "$var" newfile
   ```

   In this case, the fully expanded `$var` is considered a single string.

Comment: @anishsane  : Appreciate the edit..

Comment: I notice you have answered many [tag:bash] questions which have then been closed as duplicates. Perhaps you'll want to review the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for a list of frequently asked questions; obviously, feel free to help us out with keeping it current, understandable, and organized  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tripleee : I will take care of this in future. Was a bit lazy for this one I admit.. :)